# 2 New Wheels Causing shaking

Tags: wheels

I had to buy 2 new wheels for my car.  They put 1 new wheel on the left front and the other on the right rear.  now I have lots of wobble/shaking especially over 60 mph.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Did they balance them before they put them on? If they did, I'd suggest you should take it back to whomever did the work and have them do it again. You've paid for a service which they've either bungled or which wasn't done in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering if performance could be effected if there were a couple pounds weight difference between the new wheels and the other 2 exiting wheels.

Answer (score 0):

New wheels need balance by adding or removing weight, if the wheel is imbalanced then it will result in a lot of vibration

Comment: Best to balance the wheel , then balance the wheel and tire combination.